# CSS - Vertical align span in div

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked a lot and I have done considerable research on this point (here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere via Google, etc.) but I cannot find an answer which handles the point I am running into.

I have a dropdown with the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="box">T</div>
  <span class="phone-number">(999) 999-9999</span>
  <span class="email">temp@temp.com</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown{
  max-height: 256px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}
.dropdown .box{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown span{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

I have also made a jsfiddle with the above code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wax6st1m/).

**I am trying to figure out how to get the two `<span>`s to be vertically centered in the dropdown.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
.dropdown {
  max-height: 256px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.dropdown .box {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="box">T</div>
  <span class="phone-number">(999) 999-9999</span> 
  <span class="email">temp@temp.com</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**▶ 1<sup>st</sup> Option:**

As, in your code, you use **`display: inline-block`** for all the **`span`** elements as well as **`.box`**, you can just add **`vertical-align: middle`** to your code as follows:

```
.dropdown .box, .dropdown span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**jsFiddle** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wax6st1m/1/).

**Snippet:**

```css
.dropdown{
  max-height: 256px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}
.dropdown .box{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dropdown span{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown .box,
.dropdown span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="box">T</div>
  <span class="phone-number">(999) 999-9999</span>
  <span class="email">temp@temp.com</span>
</div>
```

---

**▶ 2<sup>nd</sup> Option:**

Another option you have is to change the display of **`.dropdown`** to **`display: flex`** and set **`align-items: center`** as shown below:

```
.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**jsFiddle** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wax6st1m/2/).

**Snippet:**

```css
.dropdown{
  max-height: 256px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}
.dropdown .box{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dropdown span{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="box">T</div>
  <span class="phone-number">(999) 999-9999</span>
  <span class="email">temp@temp.com</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one out:

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="box">T</div>
        <ul data>
            <li><span class="phone-number">(999) 999-999</span></li>
            <li><span class="email">temp@temp.com</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.data li{
    list-style:none;
}
```